# Как анимировать отрисованные в QPainter объекты?

Tags: python, анимация, pyqt, qtimer, qpainter

Не могу разобраться, как добавить анимацию к уже отрисованным объектам в `QPainter`.

Есть одно условие, новые объекты могут добавляться в любое время и их перемещения тоже должны быть анимированы.

Пробовал реализовать этот [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62224314/how-to-animate-a-point-movement-across-the-screen-in-pyqt5), но он не подходит для динамического изменения количества объектов.

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QRect, QPoint, Qt, QThread
from PyQt5 import QtGui

import time
import random
import queue

class MyThread(QThread):
    task_update_coord = pyqtSignal(QPoint, int, name = "updateCoordinate")
    def __init__(self, queue, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.queue = queue
    
    
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.x = random.randint(20, 200)
            self.y = random.randint(20, 200)
            self.id = random.randint(1, 2)
            self.task_update_coord.emit(QPoint(self.x, self.y), self.id)
            self.queue.put((self.x, self.y, self.id))
            time.sleep(1)
            print((self.x, self.y, self.id))
            

class Dialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.queue = queue.Queue()
        thread = MyThread(self.queue, parent=self)

        self.setFixedSize(600, 600)
        
        self.rect = QRect(0, 0, 10, 10)
        self.rect2 = QRect(0, 0, 10, 10)
        self.point = QPoint(10, 20)
        self.child = QWidget()
        thread.task_update_coord.connect(self.changing_coords, Qt.ConnectionType.QueuedConnection)
        thread.start()

    def changing_coords(self):
        msg = self.queue.get()
        print(msg)
        x = msg[0]
        y = msg[1]
        id = msg[2]
        self.rect = QRect(x, y, 30, 30)
        self.rect2 = QRect(x+30, y+30, 30, 30)
        self.update()
        
         
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)

        painter.drawEllipse(self.rect)
        painter.drawText(self.rect, Qt.TextFlag.TextDontClip|Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter, str(1))
        
        painter.drawEllipse(self.rect2)
        painter.drawText(self.rect2, Qt.TextFlag.TextDontClip|Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter, str(2))
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from random import randint
from typing import List
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y, r, v_x, v_y, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.r = r
        self.v_x = v_x
        self.v_y = v_y
        self.color = color

    def update(self):
        self.x += self.v_x
        self.y += self.v_y

    def draw(self, painter: QPainter):
        r, g, b = self.color
        color = QColor(r, g, b)
        painter.save()
        painter.setPen(Qt.black)
        painter.setBrush(color)
        painter.drawEllipse(self.x, self.y, self.r, self.r)
        painter.restore()

    @property
    def center(self):
        return self.x, self.y

    @property
    def top(self):
        return self.y - self.r

    @property
    def bottom(self):
        return self.y + self.r

    @property
    def left(self):
        return self.x - self.r

    @property
    def right(self):
        return self.x + self.r


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

        self._old_pos = None
        self.frame_color = Qt.darkCyan

        self.balls: List[Ball] = []

        timeout = 1000 // 60
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.tick)
        self.timer.start(timeout)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton(
            "Добавить пару шариков", 
            clicked=self._add), alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton(
            "Закрыть окно", 
            clicked=self.close), alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)

    def _add(self):        
        for i in range(2):
            self.append_random_ball()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self._old_pos:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self._old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)

    def tick(self):
        for ball in self.balls:
            ball.update()
            # Условия отскакивания шарика от левого и правого края
            if ball.left <= 0 or ball.right >= self.width():
                ball.v_x = -ball.v_x
            # Условия отскакивания шарика верхнего и нижнего края
            if ball.top <= 0 or ball.bottom >= self.height():
                ball.v_y = -ball.v_y
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setBrush(QColor(0, 0, 0, 1))
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.frame_color, 10))
        painter.drawRect(self.rect())
        for ball in self.balls:
            ball.draw(painter)

    def append_random_ball(self):
        def get_random_vector():
            pos = 0, 0
            # Если pos равен (0, 0), пересчитываем значения, т.к. шарик должен двигаться
            while pos == (0, 0):
                pos = randint(-3, 3), randint(-3, 3)
            return pos

        def get_random_color():
            return randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)

        x = self.width() // 2 + randint(-self.width() // 4, self.width() // 4)
        y = self.height() // 2 + randint(-self.height() // 4, self.height() // 4)
        
        r = randint(22, 33)
        v_x, v_y = get_random_vector()
        color = get_random_color()

        ball = Ball(x, y, r, v_x, v_y, color)
        self.balls.append(ball)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    WIDTH = 600    
    HEIGHT = 600   
    BALL_NUMBER = 10 

    w = Widget()
    w.resize(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    for i in range(BALL_NUMBER):
        w.append_random_ball()

    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, ваш пример помог мне реализовать то, что я хотел)